# How to calculate how similar a group of rows are in a dataframe using r

Tags: python, r

I have the following dataset:

```
name    date         cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4    cat5
joe     15/09/2013   A       D       C       D       NA
joe     14/09/2013   D       A       C       NA      NA
joe     13/09/2013   A       C       NA      NA      NA
jack    15/09/2013   G       I       K       D       O
jack    14/09/2013   H       G       O       M       K
```

For each person I want to calculate a percentage of how similar each of their categories are compared with each other. e.g.

```
name    percentage
joe     88.9%      
jack    60%
```

Notice that the NAs are ignored and the number of times a category appears is irrelevent.

To walk you through my logic (which may be wrong, or there may be a better way to do this, if so please say): Let's take joe as an example,

> 1. row1 (15/09/2013) compared to row2 (14/09/2013) matches 100%
> 2. row1 (15/09/2013) compared to row3 (13/09/2013) matches 66%
> 3. row2 (14/09/2013) compared to row3 (13/09/2013) matches 66%
> 4. row2 (14/09/2013) compared to row1 (15/09/2013) matches 100%
> 5. row3 (13/09/2013) compared to row1 (15/09/2013) matches 100%
> 6. row3 (13/09/2013) compared to row2 (14/09/2013) matches 100%

so the average score is 88.9%

For jack, only categories 'G', 'K', 'O' appear in both rows so the average score is 60%

I have looked into the ddply function in R, but i'm not sure if I can use it to create the dataframe above (name, percentage). My other options, one which I think I should be avoiding as I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to do it in R, is to created a R script with nested for loop..eek!

And my final option, which potentially may be the best way (as this dataframe will be quite large) is to use Python, hence if anyone knows how to do this is Python (guessing we will be using Pandas) I would be greatful for some help.

So to be clear, two questions:

1. If it is possible to use ddply can someone please show me how, else does anyone have any other ideas on how I can tackle this in r?
2. Using the small data frame above can someone provide an example of how they would tackle this problem in Python?

Comment: I am confusing : Why row2/row3 --> 66% and row3/row2 --> 100%?

Comment: It is a really boring question but I ask - [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: @agstudy I guess because all the values of row 3 are found in row 2 but since row 2 has one more non-NA value only 2/3 of row 2 are accounted for in row 3. i.e. you can't count the same one twice.

Comment: @agstudy my train of thought: row2/row3 - I'm calculating how many categories in row 2 are in row 3, hence: 2/3 = 66.6%. row3/row2 - I'm calculating how many categories in row 3 are in row 2, hence 2/2 = 100%. Hope that makes sense. Like I said if you have a better way to approach this problem, please say.

Comment: @zero323 so far I have tried to do this in R, I was in the process of creating a script (the one I mentioned above) but like I said I stopped because I wasn't sure if it was the most efficient way to do it. Then I started trying to use Python to create this but so far haven't had any luck. Not giving up though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why row2 vs row3 gives 66 %, but row1 vs row3 100 %. I don't see the logic there.

Here is an implementation of the logic as I understand it:

```
fun <- function(df) {
  M <- as.matrix(df)
  res1 <- combn(seq_len(nrow(M)), 2, function(ind) {
    i <- na.omit(intersect(M[ind[1],], M[ind[2],]))
    l <- length(unique(na.omit(M[ind[2],])))
    length(i)/l
  })
  res2 <- combn(rev(seq_len(nrow(M))), 2, function(ind) {
    i <- na.omit(intersect(M[ind[1],], M[ind[2],]))
    l <- length(unique(na.omit(M[ind[2],])))
    length(i)/l
  })
  c(res1,res2)
}

fun(DF[1:3,3:7])
#[1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

I then tried to use `ddply` with this function, but there were issues with lazy evaluation or scoping. So, I turned to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, mean(fun(.SD)), .SDcols=3:7, by=name]
#   name        V1
#1:  joe 0.8888889
#2: jack 0.6000000
```

I don't know if that is efficient enough for your data.

Comment: apologies you're right row1 vs row3 shouldn't be 100%. I'll update my original question and thank you for the response

Comment: And again, you seem to change the logic. I assumed that you only compare unique values ...

Comment: @Roland yes, I only want to compare the unique values. I think I might be having one of those days, can you explain to me why you believe the logic still doesn't work?

Comment: You have three unique values in row1 and two of those in row3. So how do you get 50 %?

Comment: Doh! Definitely going to be a long day! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `ddply` , I discover it is similar to @Roland idea:

1. group by name
2. for each group find the combinaisons of 2 rows using `combn`. `combn` is really slow maybe better to use `expand.grid`
3. for each combination of 2 rows, remove missing values and keep only unique values. Better to do this for all the data before grouping.
4. Compute 2 scores since the relation is not symmetric.

Here my code:

```
library(plyr)
id <- grep("cat*",names(dat))


compare.row <- function(x,y){
  xx <- x[id]
  xx <- unique(xx[!is.na(xx)])
  yy <- y[id]
  yy <- unique(yy[!is.na(yy)])
  v = c(length(intersect(xx,yy))/length(yy),
        length(intersect(xx,yy))/length(xx))
}


ddply(dat,.(name),function(x){
  ll <-  combn(seq(nrow(x)),2,FUN=function(i)
                 compare.row(x[i[1],],x[i[2],]))
  mean(unlist(ll))
})

 name        V1
1 jack 0.6000000
2  joe 0.8888889
```

**EDIT** add some bencmarking:

With this small data , data.table solution is the winner;

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ag(),ro(),jb(),times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 ag()  8.410804  8.790441  9.389289  9.684352 13.981724     5
 ro()  4.351227  4.765756  4.787374  5.414287  7.320817     5
 jb() 11.077366 11.413388 11.888599 11.923870 12.119946     5
```

Comment: @Roland, agstudy thank you both. I'm quite new to R so I'm going to need to sit down a have a look at your code. You both seem to have got the same percentage scores (different to what I was expecting for Joe) and hence I need to revisit my logic. Thanks again +1!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
d <- read.table(
  text='name    date         cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4    cat5
joe     15/09/2013   A       D       C       D       NA
joe     14/09/2013   D       A       C       NA      NA
joe     13/09/2013   A       C       NA      NA      NA
jack    15/09/2013   G       I       K       D       O
jack    14/09/2013   H       G       O       M       K', 
  header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(plyr)
ddply(d, 'name', function(x) {
  combns <- expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(x)), seq_len(nrow(x)))
  combns <- combns[!combns[, 1] == combns[, 2], ]
  mean(sapply(seq_len(nrow(combns)), function(i) {
    n <- sum(!is.na(unique(unlist(x[combns[i, 1], -(1:2)]))))
    sum(!is.na(match(unique(unlist(x[combns[i, 1], -(1:2)])), 
                     unique(unlist(x[combns[i, 2], -(1:2)])), 
                     incomparables=NA))) / n
  }))
})
```